# Why spring aop can't find referenced pointcut

Tags: spring, aop

I configure the required but why error ocured. I checked few docs but no proper solution. I am using annotation based aop with autoproxy. Some code snippet is there below.

business class

```
package com.jlc.spring;

public class Business1 {

    public void myBusiness() {
        System.out.println("Business1-myBusiness");

    }
    public void doMyBusiness() {
        System.out.println("Business1-doMyBusiness");

    }

}
```

aop class

```
package com.jlc.spring.service;

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;

@Aspect
public class LogService {

    /*
    @Pointcut("execution(* com.jlc.spring.Business1.*Business(..))")
    public void m1(){}

    @Pointcut("execution(* com.jlc.spring.Business1.my*(..))")
    public void m2(){}
    @Pointcut("execution(* com.jlc.spring.Business1.do*(..))")
    public void m3(){}
    */
    @Pointcut("execution(* *.*Business1.my.(..))")
    private void m2(){}
    /*
    @Before("m1()")

    public void log1(){
        System.out.println("LogService-log1");
    }
    @Before("m2()")
    public void log2(){
        System.out.println("LogService-log2");
    }
    @Before("m3()")
    public void log3(){
        System.out.println("LogService-log3");
    }
    */
    @Before("m2()")
    public void log2(){
        System.out.println("LogService-log2");
    }
}
```

config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
            xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
            xmlns:tool="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool"          
            xsi:schemaLocation="
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tool-3.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">
           <context:annotation-config/>
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
<bean id="ls" class="com.jlc.spring.service.LogService"/>

<bean id="b1" class="com.jlc.spring.Business1"/>

</beans>
```

and the error:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'b1' defined in class path resource [jlcindia.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 can't find referenced pointcut m2
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.jlc.spring.Main.main(Main.java:8)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 can't find referenced pointcut m2
    at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.PointcutParser.parsePointcutExpression(PointcutParser.java:316)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.buildPointcutExpression(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:195)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.checkReadyToMatch(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:181)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.getClassFilter(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:162)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:200)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:254)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AopUtils.java:286)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:117)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:87)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:68)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:359)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:407)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1426)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    ... 11 more
```

Comment: And the error is? Please add the error or stack trace or is it an error in the IDE only...

Comment: ya i added the stack

Comment: @Rake, can you show your `pom.xml`?

Comment: i guess pom.xml is in maven. My one is standalone no maven.

Comment: @Rake, if you haven't Maven, make shure that you have libraries jars of [**Spring AOP**](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-aop) and [**Spring Aspects**](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-aspects). On these pages choose your Spring version and download jars via `Download ( JAR )` link. Then place these jars to folder, where you store other libraries of your project

Comment: @romach I have required jars
[link](http://imgur.com/NYS93MX)

Comment: Surprisingly same thing now works in myeclipse. Befor i used keplar. do you know why?

Comment: @Rake, maybe MyEclipse uses newer versions of jars. I advise you to use automation tools such as **Apache Maven** or **Gradle** to build your projects

Answer (score 0):

Try to fix your **xml config file** that way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>

    <bean id="ls" class="com.jlc.spring.service.LogService"/>

    <bean id="b1" class="com.jlc.spring.Business1"/>

</beans>
```

Also you have error in pointcut syntax, try this:

```
@Pointcut("execution(* *.*Business1.my*(..))")
private void m2(){}
```

See examples of pointcut syntax [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#aop-pointcuts-examples).

Make sure that you have these dependencies in your **pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

My Spring version is **4.2.4.RELEASE**

Comment: thanks romach. I updated as u adviced. But still have the same issue. error stack I updated above.

Comment: where do I get this pom.xml in my app? Spring 3.1

Comment: Surprisingly same thing now works in myeclipse. Befor i used keplar. do you know why?